# How to change linewidth in LineBasicMaterial three.js

Tags: three.js

I use `Ubuntu 20.04`, `Firefox 107 x64`, and I try to change the thickness of the `LineBasicMaterial` as follows:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

 /**
 draw arrow
*/
function drawArrow(pick_pos, place_pos, line_width, scene) {
    /**
    * Curve
    */
    const start = new THREE.Vector3();
    start.add(pick_pos)
    
    const finish = new THREE.Vector3();
    finish.add(place_pos)

    let mid = new THREE.Vector3();
    mid.add(start);
    let dist = finish.x + mid.x;
    mid.x = dist/2;
    mid.y += 3;

const b_curve = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(
    start,
    mid,
    finish
);
const points = b_curve.getPoints( 100 );
const line_geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0ffffb, linewidth: line_width } );
const curve = new THREE.Line( line_geometry, material );
scene.add(curve);
}

/**
 Create the scene, camera, renderer
*/
function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x21252d);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 8;
  camera.position.z = 10;
  scene.add(camera);
  
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  
  const pick = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  const place = new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, 5);
  drawArrow(pick, place, 1, scene);

  const pick2 = new THREE.Vector3(-5, 0, -5);
  const place2 = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1);
  drawArrow(pick2, place2, 5, scene);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}

function onWindowResize() {
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.min.js"></script>
```

But as you can see it doesn't work well, can you please tell me how can I solve that? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, most WebGL implementations do not support other line widths than *1*. In fact, the WebGL spec does not require any other line width to be supported.

See more in the Three.js [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/LineBasicMaterial) under `linewidth`, and see also the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/lineWidth) on the topic.

If you need thicker lines, you can use other solutions, such as [MeshLine](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine), or implement your own screen-space quad or some similar approach.